# x64dbgpy: application unresponsive when trying to automate inside breakpoint callback

Tags: binary-analysis, python, dynamic-analysis, x64dbg, automation

When a breakpoint callback is triggered trying to automate the debugger inside the callback causes the application to become unresponsive. `x64dbg` continues functioning but the application itself doesn't resume execution.

This is only happening when the functions are called inside the BP callback.

Script:

```
from x64dbgpy import *

def handle():
    pluginsdk.Run()


Breakpoint.add(0x81755, handle)
```

Calling any function such as `pluginsdk.StepOver`, etc also causes the freeze.

Does x64dbgpy not support automating the debugger inside breakpoint callbacks? Or am I doing something wrong? Suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is not supported to do debug automation in callbacks. This is related to the threading model and is further explained at https://x64dbg.com/blog/2016/10/20/threading-model.html, which links to some older resources.

Recently there was an interesting development though, because it became possible to automate in the debug callbacks with x64dbg’s built in scripting language (which I do not recommend). The idea now is to port this idea to a C api, which can then be used by plugins like x64dbgpy or x64dbgPlaytime.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the work you do. Is there somewhere I can read about the recent developments? I looked around on GitHub but nothing stood out